# 3D interpolation of 2 lists in python

Tags: python, list, interpolation

hi i have two sets of data taken from two seperate import files which are both being imported into python and have been placed in two seperate lists as follows:

list 1 is of the form:

```
(node, x coordinate, y coordinate, z coordinate)
example list 1: [[1,0,0,0],[2,1,0,0],[3,0,1,0],[4,1,1,0],[5,0,0,1],[6,1,0,1],[7,0,1,1],[8,1,1,1]]
```

list 2 is in the form:

```
(x coordinate, y coordinate, z coordinate, temperature)
example list 2: [[0,0,0,100],[1,0,0,90],[0,1,0,85],[1,1,0,110],[0,0,1,115],[1,0,1,118],[0,1,1,100],[1,1,11,96]]
```

from these two lists I need to use the coordinates to create a third list which contains a node value and its corresponding temperature. This task is a simple dictionary function if all the x y and z coordinates match up however with the data i am working with this will not always be the case.

For example if in list 1 I add a new entry at the end of the list, node number 9;

```
new entry at end of list 1 [9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.25]
```

Now I find myself with a node number with no corresponding temperature. At this point an interpolation function will need to be performed on list 2 to give me the temperature related to this node. Through basic 3d interpolation calculations I have worked out that this temperature will be 97.9 therefore my final output list would look like this:

Output list:

```
(node, temperature)
Output list: [[1,100],[2,90],[3,85],[4,110],[5,115],[6,118],[7,100],[8,96],[9,97.9]]
```

I am reasonably new to python so am struggling to find a solution to this interpolation problem, I have been researching how to do this for a number of weeks now and have still not been able to find a solution.

Any help would be greatly **greatly** appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Look up numpy and scipy.

Comment: I have tried this but have been unable to get it to work for 3d only 2d

Comment: Well then provide what code you have.

Comment: code provided above now, cheers

Comment: There's ND interpolation in [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

Comment: @will I'm sorry to come of sounding stupid but I am just getting used new to this, could you explain what you mean or how i could incorporate it into my script.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few interpolation routines in scipy, but above 2 dimensions, most of them only offer linear and nearest neighbour interpolation - which might not be sufficient for your use.

All of the interpolation routiens are listed on the [interplation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) page of the scipy docs area. Straight away you can ignore the mnivariate, and 1D and 2D spline sections - you want the [multivariate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation) section.

There are 9 functions here, split into structured and unstructed data:

> #### Unstructured data:
>
> `griddata(points, values, xi[, method, ...])` Interpolate unstructured
>   D-dimensional data.
>
> `LinearNDInterpolator(points, values[, ...])` Piecewise linear interpolant in N dimensions.
>
> `NearestNDInterpolator(points, values)`   Nearest-neighbour interpolation in N dimensions.
>
> `CloughTocher2DInterpolator(points, values[, tol])`   Piecewise cubic, C1 smooth, curvature-minimizing interpolant in 2D.
>
> `Rbf(*args)`  A class for radial basis function approximation/interpolation of n-dimensional scattered data.
>
> `interp2d(x, y, z[, kind, copy, ...])`    Interpolate over a 2-D grid. For >
>
> #### data on a grid:
>
> `interpn(points, values, xi[, method, ...])`  Multidimensional
>   interpolation on regular grids.
>
> `RegularGridInterpolator(points, values[, ...])`  Interpolation on a regular grid in arbitrary dimensions
>
> `RectBivariateSpline(x, y, z[, bbox, kx, ky, s])` Bivariate spline approximation over a rectangular mesh.

plus an additional one in the *see also* section, though we'll ignore that.

You should read how they each work, it might help you understand a little better.

The way these functions work though, is that you pass them data i.e. `x,y,z` coords, and the corresponding values at those points, and they then return a function which allows you to get a point at any location.

I would recommend the [Rbf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf) function here though, as from what i can see it's the only nD option which does not limit you to linear or nearest neighbour interpolation.

For example, you have two lists:

```
node_locations = [(node, x_coord, y_coord, z_coord), ...]
temp_data = [(x0, y0, z0, temp0), (x1, y1, z1, temp1), ...]

xs, ys, zs, temps = zip(*teemp_data) # This will unpack your data into columns, rather than rows.

from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
rbfi = Rbf(xs, ys, zs, temps)

# I don't know how you want your output data, so i'm just dumping it in a dictionary.    
node_data = {}
for node, x, y, z in node_locations:
  node_data[node] = rbfi(x, y, z)
```

Try something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For scientific computing, I wouldn't use lists but numpy arrays instead.

So in your case:

```
import numpy as np
nodes = np.array(example_list_1)
temperatures = np.array(example_list_2)
```

With this you can then go on to use scipy's interpolation functions, like for example:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
interpolated = griddata(temperatures[:, :-1], 
                         temperatures[:, -1], 
                         nodes[:, 1:])
```

Comment: i've tried this using the example list from above and it just returns the coordinates. how could i integrate this to return my output list. Cheers